# Should we add a "Recommendation List" to the list of off topic close flags?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, off-topic

When you select to flag a question to be closed as off-topic there is 3 options which seem to have been added for the site with the other 2 looking like the generic options that all Stack Exchange sites have.

Now when a Recommendation List request question comes up and we select to close it it would be good if we could have a "Recommendation List" option there and if it works how i think it does, the comment that's automatically posted should also detail that it's off-topic but also indicate that with 20 Rep the question could be asked in the Chat Room.

I see 3 benefits to this

1. for people like me who post a comment first about it being off topic before clicking on "close" it would save up on the double comment
2. The OP would be notified about the comment to their question, reading it they may have work to get the 20 rep needed to enter the chat room, this could lead to more new users staying longer
3. For Mods who can close a question by themselves, it would look more welcoming to a new user to see this rather than a *This question does not appear to be about anime or manga within the scope defined in the* which we get when use the "other" option

NOTE: i should point out that i ask this based off my understanding on how the closing works and is subject to be completely wrong

Comment: We already have 3, which as I understand is the max for most sites. We'll need to remove one to add this. Not that I'm opposed to that (the "Creating your own anime/manga" one has basically never come up since it was added so that would be a decent choice), but it's something to think about. For now though, linking to http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic in a comment (which explicitly mentions recommendations as off-topic) is probably sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we need a specific off-topic reason for that.

- Recommendation questions can (and should) be closed as too subjective.
- List questions which don't fit the criteria could either be closed as Too Broad or if needed, a custom written off-topic reason.

Also, note that prewritten custom off-topic reasons do not give off a comment (Unlike the arbitrarily written off-topic reason).

As for commenting, I recommend **[AutoReview Comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)**. That allows you to have a premade comment to pick at the click of a button. It's very good, and I use it often on Stack Overflow.

---

Edit, due to the amount of questions that seemed to be needing this, and due to popular demand, this is now implemented. See the linked duplicate for more information.